# viewing an image reside in a vector using image watch (opencv)

Tags: c++, image, visual-studio, opencv

In my code, I have code that is similar to this one:

```
std::vector<cv::Mat> myImages=GetMyImages();
```

I want to see that images in image watch, but image watch doesn't detect myImages as image and hence doesn't show them.

How can I view one image (or all of  them) in the image watch window?

Comment: do you mean imshow()? do you want to show all the mats within the vector?

Comment: @GPPK no I mean image watch add on for visual studio (https://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/e682d542-7ef3-402c-b857-bbfba714f78d)

Comment: IF that were i, I would write a for loop and set each mat in the matrix to a temp mat and see if it can see them with that?

Comment: @GPPK This is what I am doing now, but thought maybe there is a better solution.

Comment: That's probably, the image watch extension seems to only eork on mats it can see. I'm not sure though I've not used it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It works for me (Image Watch version 1.5.1106.0): when clicking the magnifying glass right next to the element, I see the cv::Mat
[image: Inspecting a vector of cv::Mats]

Answer (score 0):

In order to Image Watch on a selection of mats within a vector you need to do this:

```
for (int n = 0; n < myImages.size(); n++)
        {
            cv::Mt tempMat = myImages[n]);
        }
```

From what I can see on the ImageWatch extension page the extension needs to speifically see a variable that is of type cv::Mat, I would assume hiding it in a vector means the extension cannot see it.

Answer (score 0):

PhilLab's solution works great for old Image Watch versions, but not for newer versions like **Image Watch 2019** with **Visual Studio 2019**.

In this case, you can directly use `imageVector[k]`.